# Image Galleries for website migrated from .com to .org

Tags: plugins, images, gallery, wordpress.com-hosting

I've migrated a website from .com to .org with all of the content for a client. This client has a large amount of images that were previously arranged in various galleries on different pages. Some of these galleries where simply just a row with 4 or 5 images fit together, and some galleries where a large amount of images put together in a mosaic style pattern. I am trying to replicate this now that they are no longer using wp.com but I have been unable to find a plugin with the same functionality as they used to have on .com.

Is there a standard way of replicating .com functionality? Or is the plugin that is available to wp.com available to use after a site is migrated?

Comment: Of course it is possible to exactly replicate a site that is moved from one domain to the other. But without details (code!) of what is going wrong it is impossible to say more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetpack is the [open-source](https://jetpack.com/) plugin maintained by Automattic that provides a large amount of WordPress.com functionality to self-hosted / .org sites.

Here's [an article](https://jetpack.com/support/tiled-galleries/) on tiled galleries, specifically.

Comment: Fitting answer, but it's not entirely correct to say Jetpack is open source "version" of WP com. WP com overall is **not** open source. Even when they use specific plugins they might (and do) run modified versions, without releasing those modifications.